# Jetpack compose onSuccess() with insert into Room DB

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room, dao

Jetpack compose with room does not perform onSuccess() action, however the data was inserted

This is my viewModel call from the screen fun:

```
DIRECTOR_ID = UUID.randomUUID()
AGENCY_ID = UUID.randomUUID()
viewModel.addDirectorAndAgency(
    director = Director(
        directorId = DIRECTOR_ID,
        directorName = directorNameValue,
        directorPhone = phoneValue,
        directorPassword = directorPasswordValue,
        agencyId = AGENCY_ID
    ),
    agency = Agency(
        agencyId = AGENCY_ID,
        agencyName = agencyNameValue
    )
) {
  
navController.navigate(Graph.MAIN) //This action is not completed 

}
```

This is my viewmodel code:

```
fun addDirectorAndAgency(agency: Agency, director: Director, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        REPOSITORY.insertDirectorAndAgency(agency = agency, director = director ) {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                onSuccess()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Database repository:

```
suspend fun insertDirectorAndAgency(director: Director, agency: Agency, onSuccess: ()-> Unit)
```

RoomRepository

```
override suspend fun insertDirectorAndAgency(
    director: Director,
    agency: Agency,
    onSuccess: () -> Unit
) {
    agencyDao.insertDirectorAndAgency(agency = agency, director = director )
}
```

RoomDao:

```
@Transaction
suspend fun insertDirectorAndAgency(director: Director, agency: Agency) {
    insertDirector(director)
    insertAgency(agency)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't write side effects in Compose, instead of waiting for a result in the Ui side with `onSuccess` you can create a SharedFlow (hot flow) for navigation events in the ViewModel, along with a custom sealed class. Then you need to listen these events in the Compose screen.

in the ViewModel:

```
private val _navigationEvents = MutableSharedFlow<NavigationEvent>()
val navigationEvents = _navigationEvents.asSharedFlow()
```

Sealed class:

```
sealed class NavigationEvent {
    object Main : NavigationEvent()
    data class Detail(val id: String) : NavigationEvent() // sample
}
```

in the Compose screen:

```
@Composable
fun Screen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.navigationEvents.collect { event ->
            when (event) {
                Main -> navController.navigate(Graph.MAIN)
                Detail -> // navigate with event.id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can send the `Main` navigation event to this flow on success in the viewModel, then your navigation should happen.